# JQuery-ui dialog, 'switching' modal option not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-dialog

It's possible to change dynamically the modal mode of a jquery ui dialog?

I' made a working example : http://jsfiddle.net/LXB2Y/ and it's looking as it's not working.

```
 $( this ).dialog("option","modal",false);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like the dialog will not reflect changes while it is open, but the changes do take effect. To show the changes you can close and then immediately reopen the dialog. This may not be the best solution.

```
                $( this ).dialog("option","modal",true)
                    .dialog("close")
                    .dialog("open");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9vVGz/

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change options on a dialog you need to do it before it you open it. Other wise you will need to interact with components of dialog like the overlay with your own code after it is open

Example:

```
/* initialize a dialog*/
$('#dialog').dialog({autoOpen:false, modal:true});


/* open a dialog from a click handler and change options*/  
$('#myButton').click(function(){
    /* change original modal option*/                         
    $('#dialog').dialog('option', 'modal', false);
    /* change title based on text of "myButton"*/
    $('#dialog').dialog('option', 'title', $(this).text())

    /* options have been changed, open dialog now */
    $('#dialog').dialog('open');                          
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Still not working with jQuery 1.11. You can simply add the overlay manually though when you want to switch from a non-modal to a modal dialog:

```
$("#dialog").dialog("widget").before("<div class='ui-widget-overlay ui-front'></div>");
```

Remove the overlay accordingly, if you want to switch from a modal to a non-modal dialog.